# Getting 404 after rewriting with .htaccess for index.php page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a domain call http://www.example.com.

On this website users come and register with a username and they get a subdomain of their username. So it gets like http://username.example.com.

When they login and go into their admin panel, they can create survey for the users to fill out. At a time they can create multiple surveys and they can give specific folder name to each survey. So like they created a survey and gave it a folder name like http://username.example.com/survey.

I have created a entry in cpanel with * so when we open http://username.example.com, so it goes to index.php and on index.php i have applied condition that if any subdomain is there then we won't show the default index page and will show the survey page, but if we are going for http://username.example.com/survey with a folder name then it is giving me 404.

Now i am rewriting rule in .htaccess to get the folder name but i am getting 404 error?

This is the rule i am having right now.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

I don't understand what will be the rule to get a folder name. I searched a lot but couldn't get it working.

Can someone please help me or guide me with this?

Thanks for any help.

Ravinder

Comment: I i unclear what the problem is? Is `http://username.example.com/survey` showing 404? What URL do you want to show.

Comment: In http://username.example.com/survey, /survey is the unique name for that specific survey, i want to get this name so i can fetch all the questions of this survey and show it to user. But i couldn't write rewrite rule for it so it is giving me 404

Comment: Once captured what URL should it be rewritten to. Is it something like `/index.php?survey=abcd` where abcd is survey name

Comment: Yes i want to get whatever comes after  http://username.example.com/ because /survey will come dynamically for each survey so if he creates  another survey he can do it like http://username.example.com/newsurvey. So i want to get the /newsurvey as a parameter or query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /index.php?survey=$1 [,QSA]
```